# Проблема с запуском Auryo на Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, аудио, electron, kubuntu

Недавно скачал приложение под названием Auryo. Это кросс-платформенный неофициальный десктопный клиент Soundcloud написанный с помощью Electron. Но при запуске этого приложения на моей OS Kubuntu 18.04, приложение открывается видна левая панель, кнопки "Библиотеки, плейлисты и т.д." Но правая часть приложения (в тоже время основная часть) где должны были быть видны треки и альбомы исполнителей не отображается, вместо этого в центре приложения видно ошибку "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null" и кнопка Reload которая ничем не помогает

Официальный сайт Auryo: https://auryo.com/

Репозиторий Auryo на GitHub: https://github.com/Superjo149/auryo/

.[image: скриншот]

Comment: а вопрос в чём?

Comment: На скрине не видно чтоли, что программа не работает.

Comment: на скрине это видно

Comment: Ну, я и спрашиваю, как исправить эту проблему, как видишь нету треков, альбомов, только "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null"

Comment: [Баг](https://github.com/Superjo149/auryo/issues/191) известный, официального решения (пока) нет.

Comment: Думаю, что вопрос имеет смысл закрыть, поскольку на него нельзя дать объективный ответ. Баг будет исправлен тогда, когда автор соизволит.

Comment: Да, перейдя по Вашей ссылке, я теперь тоже думаю, что вопрос пора закрывать.